# Gleamtech c#: FileUploader Class access the information of the empty file

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload

i am using gleamtech file uploader class to upload folder. If there is a file in the folder I uploaded, I can access the information of the folder through the file. but I want to access the information of the empty folder. how can I do?

c# code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetFolderUploader(Guid folderId, int toggle = 0)
        {

    var login = LoginInformation;
                var folder = await tmfService.GetFolder(folderId, login.ResearchId);
                var blob = await GetAzureBlobLocation(folder.Path);
                var context = Hosting.GetHttpContext();
                context.Session.Set("currentFolderId", folderId);
                context.Session.Set("researchId", login.ResearchId);
                context.Session.Set("userid", GetUserId);
                context.Session.Set("toggle", toggle);
                context.Session.Set("researcherId", login.ResearcherId);
    
                var fileUploader = new FileUploader()
                {
                    Width = CssLength.Percentage(70), //Default unit is pixels. Percentage can be specified as CssLength.Percentage(100)
                    Height = CssLength.Percentage(50),
                    Resizable = true,
                    UploadLocation = blob,
                    Id = "tmfu_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                    StateId = "tmfUploader",
                    DebugMode = true,
                    WindowOptions = new WindowOptions
                    {
                        Modal = true,
                        Title = HeliosResource.UploadFileOrFolderTitle,
    
                    },
                    Hidden = true,
                    ProductInfoRendered = false,
                    DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Window,
                    DisplayLanguage = HeliosResource.Culture.Name,
    
                };
               
                fileUploader.Uploaded += FileUploader_Uploaded;
                fileUploader.ClientEvents.Uploaded = "tmfFileUploaded";
                fileUploader.Uploading += FileUploader_Uploading;
                fileUploader.ClientEvents.Ready = "fileManagerLoading";
                return PartialView("_GetFolderUploader", fileUploader);


  }
private void FileUploader_Uploading(object sender, FileUploaderUploadingEventArgs e)
        {
            var context = Hosting.GetHttpContext();
            var folderId = context.Session.Get<Guid>("currentFolderId");
            var researchId = context.Session.Get<Guid>("researchId");
            var toggle = context.Session.Get<int>("toggle");
            var researcherId = context.Session.Get<Guid>("researcherId");
            var files = tmfService.GetTmfFolderFiles(folderId, researchId, toggle, researcherId).Result;
            foreach (var item in e.Items)
            {
                var hasfolder = item.Name.Split('\\').Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList();
                var filename = hasfolder.Last();
                var any = files.Items.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PlaceholderName)).Any(p => p.PlaceholderName.Trim() == filename);
                //item.Reject();
                if (hasfolder.Count() == 0 && any)
                {
                    item.Reject(HeliosResource.FileAllreadyExits);
                }
                else
                {
                    var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
                    var ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                    item.Rename($"{name}_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}{ext}");
                    //if (hasfolder.Count == 1)
                    //    item.Rename($"{name}_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}{ext}");
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    var dirList = hasfolder.Take(hasfolder.Count - 1);
                    //    item.Rename($"{name}_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}{ext}");
                    //}
                }

            }
        }

private void FileUploader_Uploaded(object sender, FileUploaderUploadedEventArgs e)
        {
            var context = Hosting.GetHttpContext();
            var folderId = context.Session.Get<Guid>("currentFolderId");
            var researchId = context.Session.Get<Guid>("researchId");
            var userid = context.Session.Get<Guid>("userid");

            var files = new List<TmfFileDto>();
            foreach (var item in e.Items.Where(p => p.Status == UploadItemStatus.Completed))
            {
                var file = new TmfFileDto
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    TenantId = researchId,
                    ContentType = item.ContentType,
                    Extension = Path.GetExtension(item.Name),
                    Name = item.Name,
                    IsUploaded = true,
                    FolderId = folderId,
                    AddedById = userid,
                    Size = item.SizeAsString,
                };
                files.Add(file);
            }
            var asdas = e.Items.First();
            var rr = tmfService.FileUploaded(files).Result;
            if (rr.IsSuccess)
            {
                context.Session.Set("fileIds", files.Select(x=>x.Id).ToList());
            }
        }
```

As I mentioned above. When I select a folder with a file on my computer, I can access the information of the folder.

but if there is no file in the folder I selected, this time I cannot access the folder. how do i reach?